# "UnboundLocalError: local variable '?' referenced before assignment " error on large number of iteration

Tags: python

In Python, I'm trying to iterate over 6000 URLs and download them,

when I try with a small number of iteration(4 URLs) everything works as expected.

```
with open("SECmasterURLs.txt",'r') as f:
byte_data = f.read()

count = 0       
masterurls = byte_data.splitlines()
createFolder(r"/Users/egecikrikci/Desktop/SEC Scrape/ParsedDatas")
createFolder(r"/Users/egecikrikci/Desktop/SEC Scrape/MasterDatas")
ParsedFolder = (r"/Users/egecikrikci/Desktop/SEC Scrape/ParsedDatas/")
MasterFolder = (r"/Users/egecikrikci/Desktop/SEC Scrape/MasterDatas/")

for line in masterurls:

    DataDownloader(line, ParsedFolder, MasterFolder)
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    __memoryusage__ = (process.memory_info().rss)  # in bytes 
    print (__memoryusage__ / 1000000)
```

and as output it creates 2 files as expected and downloads my 4 files from URLs listed in SECmasterURLs.txt.

But when I try with 6000 URL's it returns an error:

```
    UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-cc04452d2aa1> in <module>
     11 for line in xx:
     12 
---> 13     DataDownloader(line, ParsedFolder, MasterFolder)
     14     process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
     15     __memoryusage__ = (process.memory_info().rss)  # in bytes

<ipython-input-27-1ffb4717a449> in DataDownloader(file_url, folderforparsed, folderformaster)
     25 
     26     # define a new dataset with out the header info.
---> 27     data_format = data[start_ind + 1:]
     28 
     29     master_data = []

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'start_ind' referenced before assignment
```

and here is the code inside DataDownloader:

```
def DataDownloader(file_url, folderforparsed, folderformaster):

    urlsplit = file_url.split('/')
    urlsplit2 = urlsplit[8].split('.')
    filenamebuilder = '{}{}'.format(urlsplit2[0],urlsplit2[1] + '.txt')

    MasterFiles = open(folderforparsed + 'parsed' + filenamebuilder, 'w')

    content = requests.get(file_url).content
    count = 0 

    with open(folderformaster + filenamebuilder, 'wb') as f:
         f.write(content)
    # let's open it and we will now have a byte stream to play with.
    with open(folderformaster + filenamebuilder,'rb') as f:
         byte_data = f.read()

    # Now that we loaded the data, we have a byte stream that needs to be decoded and then split by -------.
    data = byte_data.decode("utf-8").split('----')

    # We need to remove the headers, so look for the end of the header and grab it's index
    for index, item in enumerate(data):
        if "ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/" in item:
            start_ind = index

    # define a new dataset with out the header info.
    data_format = data[start_ind + 1:]

    master_data = []

    # now we need to break the data into sections, this way we can move to the final step of getting each row value.
    for index, item in enumerate(data_format):

        # if it's the first index, it won't be even so treat it differently
        if index == 0:
            clean_item_data = item.replace('\n','|').split('|')
            clean_item_data = clean_item_data[8:]
        else:
            clean_item_data = item.replace('\n','|').split('|')

        for index, row in enumerate(clean_item_data):

            # when you find the text file.
            if '.txt' in row:

                # grab the values that belong to that row. It's 4 values before and one after.
                mini_list = clean_item_data[(index - 4): index + 1]

                if len(mini_list) != 0:
                    mini_list[4] = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/" + mini_list[4]
                    master_data.append(mini_list)




    #loop through each document in the master list.
    for index, document in enumerate(master_data):

        # create a dictionary for each document in the master list
        document_dict = {}
        document_dict['cik_number'] = document[0]
        document_dict['company_name'] = document[1]
        document_dict['form_id'] = document[2]
        document_dict['date'] = document[3]
        document_dict['file_url'] = document[4]

        master_data[index] = document_dict


    for document_dict in master_data:

        # if it's a 10-K document pull the url and the name.
        if document_dict['form_id'] == '10-K':

            # get the components
            comp_name = document_dict['company_name']
            docu_url = document_dict['file_url']
            form_type = document_dict['form_id']

            print('-'*100)
            print(comp_name)
            print(docu_url)
            print('Form Type is: {}'.format(form_type))
            MasterFiles.write('-'*75)
            MasterFiles.write('\n')
            MasterFiles.write(comp_name)
            MasterFiles.write('\n')
            MasterFiles.write(docu_url)
            MasterFiles.write('\n')
            MasterFiles.write(form_type)
            MasterFiles.write('\n')
            count = count + 1
```

Comment: A few things: Why are you reading and writing the file with the result of the request as bytes? Also, you're mixing multiple variable naming conventions, just stick to `lower_case_with_underscores` for for variables and functions. Finally, it seems that the output (the content of `MasterFiles`) is being written in some random format, why not use something more standard like CSV or JSON?

Comment: I forgot to add: You should *really* use pathlib to manipulate file paths, doing everything manually is risky and makes the code needlessly lengthy. Same thing with URLs. Overall, this code could benefit from being split into multiple functions. You could separate the IO and actual processing, for example.

Comment: Another thing: The code for `masterurls` is needlessly complex and inefficient, you can iterate over `f` directly to get the lines.

Comment: Questions like this require a [mcve]. However, you should first research what this error means and how it is caused. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I am trying to teach myself coding while doing my capstone project. So all this is investigating the files to extract and dump all my knowledge to get to the solution. 

I have been thinking about ways to split my inner loops in the most logical and also I really don't know what I'm doing with that MasterFiles and also how I'm going read it again :D so rather than creating multiple files, I will put all into a single JSON file.

Can you suggest any concepts for me to Google, that would make my code better and logical and modern :D

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that when your code hits this line

```
data_format = data[start_ind + 1:]
```

it blows up because start_ind has not be initialized.

That variable is initialized via these lines:

```
for index, item in enumerate(data):
        if "ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/" in item:
            start_ind = index
```

So if the data does not include that string, start_ind will never be initialized. For some subset of the 6000 urls you're processing, that string must not be there.